# sequelize where x2 nested equal variable

Tags: reference, nested, include, sequelize.js, where-clause

I do not understand how to perform the following query:

**explanation:**

- In words:

I am trying to filter my outcomes based on a value which is within a Table, which is associated to a Table which is associated to the Model I'm trying to filter.

- associations graphic:

FilteredModel <--(hasMany)-- MiddleModel --(hasone)--> LastModel

```
FilteredModel.findAll({
  where: {
    ...conditions,
    ['$MiddleModel.LastModel.property$']: VARIABLE
  }
});
```

I have included the necessary models and I receive the value of the property I sought in the outcome.

I just do not understand how to add it to the `where` considerations.

I tried the provided example in many forms as suggested in other SOF answers, receiving a: `SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'FilteredModel->MiddleModel->LastModel.property' in 'where clause'` error.

May I have some guidance here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try below code -

```
Db.orders.findAll({
    where: { ORDER_CONDITION  },
    attributes: [ORDER ATTRIBUTES],
    include: [
        {
            where: { INNER1_WHERE },
            required: true,
            model: INNER1,
            include: [
                {
                    where: { INNER2_WHERE },
                    required: true,
                    model: INNER2
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
});
```

**required: true** param in include plays an important role of only including those orders whose includes are present

Also in your code, I didn't see the include option but you are using where condition on an include attributes **['$MiddleModel.LastModel.property$']: VARIABLE**

Comment: It is neat and works and you're amazing
thank you so much!!